# Installing Django and related packages on an offline computer

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools

I'm using win7, python 2.7 and I have a project with several packages running.
I wanted to move the project to my friends laptop (which can't access to internet, not an option). so I downloaded Python/Django/All required packages, Installed python and run `python setup.py install` in each package directory.

I've found that some packages, even after I download them, requires somethings from the internet to be downloaded and causes error. so:

How can I download a package and all it's dependencies or what ever it needs to be installed offline?

Comment: Uh, `django 2.7`? :/

Comment: There is a Python 2.7 today but Django 2.7, not to my knowledge :P

Comment: Your question is too broad as it probably depends on individual needs that aren't clear here, but most of your issues can probably be solved with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and a decent source control

Comment: sry for version problem :\

Comment: ok, I know it's a bad idea, but you can create a virtualbox image and use it on other system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can do it

- Install Django and all related packages to [a Python virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html)
- Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` which will list all installed packages and their versions in this file
- Use `pip wheel -r requirements.txt` command which builds a `wheelhouse` folder of the package list
- Zip this folder
- Go to your friend's computer, unzip
- create virtual environment and run `pip install wheelhouse/*` (Install all packages from the wheelhouse)

More [about pip wheel](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_wheel/).

Python and pip needs to be separately copied and installed.

Comment: There are never bad questions. It just takes some comments, edits and understanding to get the problem right.